# Does Connections affect your ability to use a jump clone?

Tags: eve-online

Does the standings boost from connections influence your ability to get a jump clone?

For example, if you have 7.9 standings, and >8 standings with connections, are you able to place a jump clone in a station with that corp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you meet the requirements - no matter by what methods - you can place jump clones.